# setState is not updating value in react Componet

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to update a state in my react component.  I call the function:

```
async removeActivePaymentMethod() { 
  console.log('activePaymentMethod',this.state.activePaymentMethod); //value is 20289
  const order = this.state.order;
  order.activePaymentMethod = null;
  await this.setState({ activePaymentMethod: null, order },function () {
    console.log('activePaymentMethod',this.state.activePaymentMethod);//value is 20289
});
```

}

As you can see, my console.log call is within the callback for setState.  Why is this value not updating to null?

Comment: Bizzare. Also somewhat on-topic, what's the reasoning behind `order.activePaymentMethod = null` looks like a state mutation.

Comment: and why use await when you are passing a callback to set state?

Comment: setState does not return a promise, so there is no point in awaiting it. But it is indeed bizarre.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other state updates that batch together with this and override null?

Comment: seems to work here https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/delete-me-6

Comment: [Please create a minimum, complete, and reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  The code as given does not seem to have any issues.  What is the context of this behavior?

Comment: @AvinKavish - yes, that is exactly what was happening, another setState call was overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that without noticing you are altering your state.
In these lines:

```js
const order = this.state.order;
order.activePaymentMethod = null;
```

What happens is that `order` is a reference to the `order` value in the state, and when you alter it you change the same reference `this.state.order` references.
To test that I suggest you log the values of `this.state.order.activePaymentMethod` and `order.activePaymentMethod` after the second line. 
To fix that, you should destruct your state object like so:

```js
const order = {...this.state.order, activePaymentMethod: null};
```

Which would create a new instance of the `order` object.

This happens because of the way react compares objects in the state - react uses referential equality, rather than deep value equality, and when you pass the altered `order` object it does not detect a change (both state and `order` refer to the same object).

Comment: but `order` and `activePaymentMethod` are different variables, please look at the code.